# Group fields by id mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to transform the ID as the key of the object returned in the data below?

Data:

```
{
{"_id":"5c62d9693ec4721d2ab07f70",
 "moviesRated":[
                  {"movieID":"A0",
                   "rating":"3"}
               ]
},
{"_id":"5c62d9693ec4721d2ab07f71",
 "moviesRated":[
                  {"movieID":"A1",
                   "rating":"3"}
               ]
}
}
```

Expected return:

```
{
{
    "5c62d9693ec4721d2ab07f70": {
        "A0": "3"
    }
}, {
    "5c62d9693ec4721d2ab07f71": {
        "A1": "3"
    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That looks like an invalid JSON object. Are the first curly braces supposed to be square braces like a list of objects?

Comment: Sorry @Ivan86, I edited the question and now seems to be correct.